# When I multiply seconds by 1000, Alarm never rings

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this piece of code that takes in the date selected by the user and makes an epochSecond time out of the time the user selects.

```
_itemUIState.value = itemUIState.value.copy(timeDue = time.toEpochSecond(_itemUIState.value.selectedDate,ZoneOffset.UTC))
```

I am also setting an alarm with this code

```
fun setAlarm(listItem: ListItem, context: Context) {
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("list_item", listItem)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND )
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, listItem.id!!, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val mainActivityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val basicPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, listItem.id, mainActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val clockInfo = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo((listItem.timeDue!!*1000), basicPendingIntent)
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(clockInfo, pendingIntent)
    }
```

My problem is that on the second to last line in the alarm code, if I dont multiply the seconds by 1000 (since listItem.timeDue is seconds since the 1970 epoch), then the alarm rings immediately. Which makes sense since seconds are much less and thus not multiplying by 1000 makes the time look like somewhere in the past.

However, when I multiply by 1000, the alarm never rings. What could I be doing wrong?

PS: The `AlarmClockInfo` needs the trigger time to be in milliseconds since epoch. That's why I am multiplying the `timeDue` from the first code snippet by 1000

Comment: What is time?  You're calling toEpochSecond on it, but we have no idea what it is.  And are you sure the timezone is correct?  If you're getting the UTC time it should ring at and you're in, say EST, you could need to wait hours for it to go off

Comment: I don't recognize this as `Java`. Are the tags correct?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer it's kotlin code but the API being used is a java one- java.time

Comment: @GabeSechan time is of type LocalTime from java.time.LocalTime

Comment: @GabeSechan, your comment helped me spot the problem. I tried setting the alarm 3 hours back (I am in GMT+3) and it still rang immediately. I tried setting +2 minutes ahead of 3 hours back and the alarm waited for 2 minutes before ringing. It appears that the first snippet of code is the problem. I need to convert time to epoch second while keeping catering to the user's time zone